# Need to extract latitude and longitude from a text string

Tags: r

I have a dataframe that contains latitude and longitude in this format (41.848374, -74.099412).  I need to put latitde in 1 column and longitude in another.  I have tried various R functions including gub, substr, sub and have not been able to solve this problem.  Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use a combination of `read.table` and `gsub`.  Remove the `()` part with `gsub` and use `read.table` with `sep=","` to read the strings as a two column `data.frame`.

```
read.table(text=gsub("[()]", "", str1), header=FALSE, sep=",")
#      V1        V2
#1 41.84837 -74.09941
```

#### data

```
str1 <- '(41.848374, -74.099412)'
```

Comment: Thanks for the speedy reply; this is exactly what I needed.

Answer (score 1):

Excellent solution there. Wanted to add another option for the case where you may want to read in the data as-is and then later split it up to do some analysis. You can use the `stringr` package

```
library(stringr)
```

Sample data with the addition of city names

```
mydata <- data.frame(cities = c('New Haven','Grand Rapids','Portland'),
coords = c("(41.308273,-72.927887)",
           "(42.963795,-85.670006)",
           "(45.5230  ,-122.676483)"))
```

Clean the data using gsub just as Akrun answered

```
mydata$clean_coords <- gsub(pattern = '[()]', 
replacement = '', x = mydata$coords)
```

Create the splits using the stringr package. This splits the string based on the ',' pattern into n = 2 columns.

```
split_coords <- str_split(string = mydata$clean_coords, 
pattern = ',', n = 2, simplify = TRUE)

#      [,1]        [,2]         
# [1,] "41.308273" "-72.927887" 
# [2,] "42.963795" "-85.670006" 
# [3,] "45.5230"   "-122.676483"
```